# React: Click on a component to change parents state

Tags: reactjs

Pretty new to React, can't quite figure out how to fix this.
I want to click on a component (Project) and have this change the state of the parent, determining what is then rendered.

**App.js**, in the App component, has

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    load: ''
  }
}

handleClick(e){
  this.setState({load: e.target.value});
  console.log("Clicked!");
  console.log(e);
  console.log(e.target.value);
}

display(load){
  if (load === 'bmi') {
    return <Bmi />
  }
  else return "";
}

render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">

      <div className="App-header">

        <h2>Projects</h2>

      </div>
      <div className="box">
        <Project projectName="BMI Calculator"
           projectDescription="A simple React program, using sliders to select weight and height to calculate BMI."
           imgAddress="https://cdn.vertex42.com/ExcelTemplates/Images/bmi-chart.gif"
           value="bmi"
           onClick={this.handleClick}/>

        <Project projectName="..."
           projectDescription="..."

        <Project projectName="Something Else"
           projectDescription="Describing that other thing that I did." />
      </div>
      <div className={this.state.item}>
        {this.display(this.state.item)}
      </div>

  </div>

);
}
```

Project is called from **Project.js**, which has:

```
render(){
    return(
        <div className="third" value={this.props.value} onClick={this.props.onClick}>

            <h3>{this.props.projectName}</h3>

            <div className="container">

                <img src={this.props.imgAddress} className="image" />

                <div className="middle">

                    <div className="text">{this.props.projectDescription}</div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    )
}
```

When I click on the first  the console shows:

```
clicked!
Proxy {dispatchConfig: Object, _targetInst: ReactDOMComponent, nativeEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", target: img.image…}
undefined
```

Because of the target: img.image shown in the console, I tried giving that element th same value, onClick properties as **div.third**, but that didn't work. 
I then tried giving that to all the elements in the render of Project.js but that did not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the props directly if you create an intermediate click handler in the child component:

**App.js**

```
handleClick (value) {
  console.log('clicked', value);
  this.setState({load: value});
}
```

**Project.js**

```
_onClick = () => {
  this.props.onClick(this.props.value);
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="third" onClick={this._onClick}>
      <h3>{this.props.projectName}</h3>
      <div className="container">
        <img src={this.props.imgAddress} className="image" />
        <div className="middle">
          <div className="text">{this.props.projectDescription}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here `_onClick` uses the props directly instead of dealing with the event. You will need to use the [property initializer syntax for es6](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#autobinding) classes because es6 classes do not autobind: `_onClick = () => {}`

Comment: That did it! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the function as a prop from the parent to the child. **Don't forget to use .bind(this), it was missing in your project**... at the constructor level, or at component level with this.handleClick.bind(this). You can also use _handleClick instead of handleClick (does the same).

```
// PARENT
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { name: 'bob' }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.setState({
     name : 'anita'
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      {this.state.name} 
      <Child handleClick={this.handleClick} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

// CHILD
class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.props.handleClick} />
  }
}
```